# how to convert mysql query to laravel querybuilder

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-query-builder

I try to convert my query to `laravel` query builder but i cant get succeed, my query is in `mysql` as below:

```
SELECT p.seller, p.purchase_date, p.report_no FROM purchases AS p UNION SELECT ps.seller, ps.purchase_date, ps.report_no FROM purchase_solds AS ps ORDER BY purchase_date DESC
```

So how do i convert it into laravel query-builder or laravel eloquent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried

```
$purchases = DB::table('purchases')
                 ->select('seller', 'purchase_date', 'report_no');

$purchase_solds = DB::table('purchase_solds')
                      ->select('seller', 'purchase_date', 'report_no')
                      ->union($purchases)
                      ->orderBy('purchase_date', 'desc')
                      ->get();
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it gives me error `Method getBindings does not exist`

Comment: Hi, I've updated the code, could you please check again!